# How can i make and update a text in Phaser (HTML)

Tags: html, phaser-framework

I made a variable that displays a number through `game.add.text(...)` in the create function but i want the text to update every time i press a button, since the variable changes. And if i do `game.add.text(...)` in the update function it gets stacked and many many layers of text appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple version that should give you an idea of how to handle this.

```
<script>
    var game = new Phaser.Game(400, 300, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create });
    // You'll need to make sure your button click action can access the number to display.
    var clickCount = 0;
    // We'll also need to keep track of the text object that we add to the game.
    var clickCounter;

    function preload() {
        game.load.image('button', 'assets/button.png');
    }

    function create() {
        game.stage.backgroundColor = '#124184';
        // When creating the text object, make sure it'll be accessible from our button handler.
        clickCounter = game.add.text(5, 5, 'Total clicks: ' + clickCount, { fill: '#ffffff', font: '14pt Arial' });

        game.add.button(200, 150, 'button', actionOnClick, this);
    }

    function actionOnClick() {
        clickCount++;
        // The key here is setText(), which allows you to update the text of a text object.
        clickCounter.setText('Total clicks: ' + clickCount);
    }
</script>
```

So, instead of creating a new text object, store a reference to the one you create and use `setText()` to update it.

Comment: Thanks! Works great so far

Comment: Although i have a small problem. I cant add my own image to it. I replaced the "assets/button.png" to just "button.png" which the button image is named. But there is no image in the actual game and the button dissapears. But when i do the "button.png" to something that doesnt exist then the button appears as that green square. Is there any way i can do styling to the button? without adding an actual image

Comment: If you look at the network tab in your browser and refresh does it show a 404 when loading the image? And yes, you could manually draw a background, or use a text element and style it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

clickBtn:number = 0; // for example

game.add.text('Clicks ' + this.clickBtn);

this.btn = this.add.button(some code, this.yourFunction);

this.yourFunction() {

this.clickBtn += 1;

}

I think it would help you.

Regards, Sergey.